# (Ordered) Configuration space in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, configuration-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and denote by $F_n(X)$ the following subspace:
$$F_n(X):=\{(x_1,\cdots ,x_n)\in X^n: x_i\neq x_j \forall i\neq j\}.$$
Note that, we are not considering the quotient of $F_n$ by $\Sigma_n$. Is there a decent analogue of this construction for general schemes?

Basically, one could consider the naive translation in algebraic geometry, but from my experience, this is usually not the right way to go.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: What is the problem with applying this definition directly to schemes?

Comment: Well, the first problem is, what should points be? prime ideals? geometric points?

Comment: If $X$ is a separated scheme over $S$, you can take  $F_2(X)$ to be  the complement $X\times_S X-\Delta$. Similarly for any $n$, take the complement  of the "big" diagonal in $X^n = X\times_S X\ldots$ This looks pretty reasonable.

Comment: That seems to be the type of definition that would work best. However, what if $\geq 2$? what if $X$ is not separated? Is there an established analogue of this for schemes?

Comment: @DonuArapura For any $n$, the complement of the 'big' diagonal does not agree with the definition of $F_n$, if I am not mistaken. For example, when $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $n=$, in the complement of the diagonal is $\mathbb{R}^3$ without the diagonal line. However, $F_3(\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus the three diagonal planes $x=y,x=z,y=z$.

Comment: I had in mind the complement of the *biggest* thing that could be called a diagonal, i.e. the locus where two coordinates are equal. More precisely, $x_i=x_j$ corresponds to a closed immersion $X^{n-1}\to X^n$. Take the union of all of these, and then form the complement.

Comment: @DonuArapura Fair enough. I can see that definition working. Thank you for your suggestion. If I may ask, is this the analogue people are using for schemes?